# How to retrieve the latest data on duplicates in this database?

Tags: sql, join, odbc, filemaker

I'm working with a terribly designed database which doesn't contain a primary key in most tables.
For this reason I need to tweak a few things to retrieve the information I want from the database.

I have the first table named Customer, which contains an unique identifier called customer_id. It also contains Account_ID. It contains more data which
I don't need right now.

The second table I'm working with called Contact also contains Account_ID, while it isn't unique it is the only data I can use to link
with the other table. To help with the fact that it isn't unique (for some reason a new row with the same Account_ID value is added instead of modifying one.)
I would like to retrieve the latest data that was inserted in the database where the are duplicates on the Account_ID. Luckily, there is
a Time_stamp value in this table. I suppose I could use that to my advantage.

I should add that this is a filemaker database, so while I tried a few things I already found here on SO it doesn't always seem to work, I assume for that reason.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.Customer, table1.Account_ID, table2.Account_ID, table2.Phone"
           . "FROM Customer AS table1"
                . "JOIN Contact AS table2 ON table1.Account_id = table2.Account_id";
```

This query works, but doesn't exclude duplicates or look for the latest Account_ID entry in the Contact table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is ok. i just added a where clause to filter the one with the newest timestamp. it should work on sql server, dont know about filemaker. good luck :)

```
SELECT Customer.customer_id, Customer.Account_ID, Contact.Account_ID, Contact.Time_stamp
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Contact ON Customer.Account_ID = Contact.Account_ID
WHERE Contact.Time_stamp = (SELECT MAX(C.Time_stamp) FROM Contact C WHERE C.Account_ID = Contact.Account_ID);
```

[test the query here](http://ideone.com/uFUaDH)

Answer (score 0):

use this query to remove duplicate in your query:

```
"SELECT distinct table1.Customer, table1.Account_ID, table2.Account_ID, table2.Phone,max(table2.Account_ID)"
           . "FROM Customer AS table1"
                . "JOIN Contact AS table2 ON table1.Account_id = table2.Account_id"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesn't seem to work (giving errors). When I deleted this: max(table2.Account_ID) from the query it worked, but not the way I want obviously. I seem to notice MAX is giving me issues, as if I can't use it. Is there a way around it?

Comment: you cannot use an aggregate function here without group by.